# Cloudflare websocket returns only one value of Date.now()

Tags: javascript, websocket, cloudflare

Ok so i made a websocket in cloudflare workers which creates a variable connectime when client connects with Date.now() and also when it disconnects. Then it calculates the difference and logs client disconnected after a connection of --ms, where -- is the difference between times..

```
addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})


async function handleRequest(request) {
    const connecttime = Date.now();


const upgradeHeader = request.headers.get('Upgrade');
    if (!upgradeHeader || upgradeHeader !== 'websocket') {
      return new Response('Expected Upgrade: websocket', { status: 426 });
    }
  
    const webSocketPair = new WebSocketPair();
    const [client, server] = Object.values(webSocketPair);
        server.accept();

//Do something



server.addEventListener('close', event => {
        const endtime = Date.now();
        console.log(endtime);
        const contime = endtime-connecttime;
        console.log("client disconnected after a connection of " + contime + "ms");
    })
```

The problem is it returns 0 value;

`client disconnected after a connection of 0ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design and part of the security model of Cloudflare Workers - from the documentation:

> Workers is designed to make it impossible for code to measure its own
> execution time locally. For example, the value returned by Date.now()
> is locked in place while code is executing. No other timers are
> provided.

For a full explanation, I recommend the [following documentation page](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/security-model/#step-1-disallow-timers-and-multi-threading)